# window.open() and window.print() in the new window blocks javaScript in parent window

Tags: javascript

The following code is on say window A:

```
var printWindow = window.open(url, "print_apt_window");
if(printWindow) {
     printWindow.focus();
}
```

In window B:

```
onPrintViewReady(function () {
            window.print();
});
```

This works fine but only one big problem, It blocks javascripts, links and even page refresh in window A.

Please help me with some works around. Thanks :)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zicane/7ntsb7hh/10/

Comment: _"It blocks javascripts, links and even page refresh in window A"_ Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to reproduce issue? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is this even a Chrome App?

Comment: A similar issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Zicane/7ntsb7hh/10/